# Getting the text of label once button is clicked (Tkinter)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am new to Python and Tkinter so I am trying to create a sample program to explore.

The program basically shows the names as a Label then 4 buttons will be put right next to the Label.

One of the buttons is "Delete" and what I want to do is, the button will get the name of the Label that is right next to that 'Delete" button.

The code is :

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.namelist = ["Mark","Anna","Jason","Lenna",
                     "Leo","Zucharich","Robinson",
                     "AReallyLongNameThatMightExist"]
        self.canvas = Canvas(width=1200,height=700)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)

    def Friends(self):
        frame = Frame(self.canvas)
        frame.place(x=600,y=300)
        #Frame for showing names of friends
        row = 0
        for x in self.namelist:
            label = Label(frame,text="%s "%x)
            chatButton = Button(frame,text="Chat")
            delButton = Button(frame,text="Delete")
            setcloseButton = Button(frame,text="Set Close")
            setgroupButton = Button(frame,text="Set Group")
            label.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="W")
            chatButton.grid(row=row, column=1)
            delButton.grid(row=row, column=2)
            setcloseButton.grid(row=row, column=3)
            setgroupButton.grid(row=row, column=4)
            row = row + 1
        mainloop()

GUI = GUI()
GUI.Friends()
```

Example: If you run the code, then when you click "Delete" button next to "Mark", then the button will return "Mark".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tk buttons have a *command* option to allow you to specify code to be run when the button is clicked. In this case you just want to pass the sibling widget name to your function. You can do this by capturing the widget name at creation time:

```
label = ...
delButton = Button(frame,text="Delete",
                   command=self.makeClosure(label))
...
def makeClosure(self, labelWidget):
    return lambda: self.onClick(labelWidget)
def onClick(self, labelWidget):
    print(labelWidget["text"])
```

In this example, when we create the *delButton* widget, the command is defined as a lambda that creates a closure including the label variable as it is defined at the time when this lambda is defined. Now when the *delButton* is clicked, this value will be passed to the *onClick* function which can use this to call methods on the widget at runtime.